# Usefull functionlity hidden away in Development/Shake/FilePattern.hs

Tags: shake-build-system

I'm trying to use the function **extract** defined in **Development.Shake.FilePattern** but it's hidden. Why? It's not used internally either from what I can gather.

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> import Development.Shake.FilePattern

<no location info>: 
    Could not find module `Development.Shake.FilePattern'
    it is a hidden module in the package `shake-0.15.10'
Prelude>
```

**extract** would be really handy. Currently I have to resort to custom string manipulations instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extract` is used internally to implement the user-visible `&%>` function.

Shake deliberately tries to avoid leaking internal implementation details - for example it contains a thread-pool implementation, which it keeps quiet. That said, clearly `FilePattern` are useful, so:

- Since Shake v0.16 there is a function `filePattern`, which does what is requested above.
- The `FilePattern` functionality in Shake has been released as [the `filepattern` library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepattern), which Shake will use for all its functionality.